# Add .aar libraries which are abi specific

Tags: android, gradle, abi

When compiling LibVLC for Android, you will get one AAR file per ABI, and I would like to know how it would be possible to add one dependency per ABI.

First try, packagingOptions:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI) == "armeabi-v7a") {
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-arm64-v8a.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-x86_64.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-x86.aar'
            }
        } else if (output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI) == "arm64-v8a") {
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-armeabi-v7a.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-x86_64.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-x86.aar'
            }
        } else if (output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI) == "x86_64") {
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-arm64-v8a.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-armeabi-v7a.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-x86.aar'
            }
        } else if (output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI) == "x86") {
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-arm64-v8a.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-armeabi-v7a.aar'
                exclude 'libs/libvlc-3.0.13-x86_64.aar'
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...
dependencies{
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

I got an error, saying that android task has already been created

Second try:

```
def currentAbi = ""

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        currentAbi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
    }
}

// ...

dependencies{
    implementation fileTree(include: ["libvlc-3.0.13-${currentAbi}.aar"], dir: 'libs')
}
```

But I guess currentAbi value is not changing because my VLC classes are not included.

So if anyone has a solution to add dependency to an aar library which is ABI specific, it would be a great help.

Thanks